# Any benefit of using onError and onCompleted callbacks instead of variables in apollo-client

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client

I have a component using `apollo-client` with react where I was originally using the `onError` and `onCompleted` callbacks to set data once it is received, or render an error message. This is how the component with `useLazyQuery` hook looked:

```js
export const StationCard = ({ stationData }) => {
  const { name, parking, stationNumber } = stationData;
  const [showMoreInfo, setShowMoreInfo] = useState(false);
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const [getMoreInfo, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(STATION_DETAILS, {
    onCompleted: data => setFetchedData(data.stationWithStationNumber),
    onError: error => {
      setError(true);
      console.error(error);
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showMoreInfo) {
      getMoreInfo({ variables: { stationNumber } });
    }
  }, [showMoreInfo]);

  return (
    // only for demonstration
    <div></div>
  )
}
```

Once I refactored it to use the variables `data` and `error` that we get by default from `useLazyQuery` and `useQuery`, I was able to remove a lot of un-needed and redundant `useState`s, which I think would also have reduced many re-renders as the state is not being updated as frequently now:

```js
export const StationCard = ({ stationData }) => {
  const { name, parking, stationNumber, picture } = stationData;
  const [showMoreInfo, setShowMoreInfo] = useState(false);

  const [getMoreInfo, { loading, data, error }] = useLazyQuery(STATION_DETAILS);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showMoreInfo) {
      getMoreInfo({ variables: { stationNumber } });
    }
  }, [showMoreInfo]);

  return (
   // only for demonstration
   <div></div>
  );
};
```

So are there any use cases when the callbacks are actually useful and preferable over the variables offered by `useQuery`/`useLazyQuery` or are the callbacks redundant and non-performant?

Comment: Well, there are a potentially infinite amount of use cases for `onError`, but as you show, your code gets much more readable. Now, one could make a case for `useLazyQuery` also being a wrong fit here. instead, you could use `skip`: `useQuery(STATION_DETAILS, { variables: ..., skip: !showMoreInfo })` and now you even delete the effect.

Comment: Are there cases where the callbacks are definitely needed? You could name just some major ones off the top of your head, 'cause I was unable to think of any that couldn't be done with the variables in a more succinct manner. I was really wondering about what am I missing out to not be able to think of such cases.

Comment: Log errors, trigger a toast, whatever imperative API you want to call

Comment: fetched data [shape] conversion - decode/flatten/whatever required but not API supported - effect can be used (with conditions)